# Rails/ActiveRecord: Eager loading join table entries via a composite primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading, composite-primary-key

I'm having issues eager loading a join table with ActiveRecord in Rails (4.2.4) (w/MySQL).  The issue is that the join table makes use of a composite primary key, which is causing some weird? behaviour with the eager load.  Here's an example to clarify:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_student_joins
  has_many :courses, through: :course_student_joins
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_student_joins
  has_many :students, through: :course_student_joins
end

class CourseStudentJoin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end

Table: courses

id  name
1   Course 1
2   Course 2

Table: students

id  name
1   Joey
2   Johnny
3   Dee Dee

Table: course_student_joins

course_id   student_id  extra_id
    1           1           5
    2           2           6
```

So course_student_joins is a classic many to many join table.  Here's the interesting bit, if the PRIMARY KEY on the course_student_joins table consists of just course_id (single field), this works:

```
> Course.eager_load(:course_student_joins).first.course_student_joins

Result:

  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT `courses`.`id` AS t0_r0, `courses`.`name` AS t0_r1, `course_student_joins`.`course_id` AS t1_r0, `course_student_joins`.`student_id` AS t1_r1, `course_student_joins`.`extra_id` AS t1_r2 FROM `courses` LEFT OUTER JOIN `course_student_joins` ON `course_student_joins`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id` WHERE `courses`.`id` = 1 AND `courses`.`id` IN (1)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<CourseStudentJoin course_id: 1, student_id: 1, extra_id: 5>]>
```

If the PRIMARY KEY is changed (database side) to a composite key of (course_id, student_id), which is what we want (as a course can't have the same student twice and the primary key needs to be unique), this is what we get:

```
> Course.eager_load(:course_student_joins).find_by(id:1).course_student_joins

Result:

  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT `courses`.`id` AS t0_r0, `courses`.`name` AS t0_r1, `course_student_joins`.`course_id` AS t1_r0, `course_student_joins`.`student_id` AS t1_r1, `course_student_joins`.`extra_id` AS t1_r2 FROM `courses` LEFT OUTER JOIN `course_student_joins` ON `course_student_joins`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id` WHERE `courses`.`id` = 1 AND `courses`.`id` IN (1)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Note the empty collection in the second result, and the SQL that remains exactly the same in both (expected).

We've played with foreign_key, primary_key settings on the has_many declarations, and even a 'solution' that changes the loading to reflect how it was performed in rails 2.0 and below.  Also played with includes/references as well.  No luck, any/all help appreciated.

The end goal is to come up with an ActiveRecord collection of courses with eagerly joined students and the entries in the join table, as we need to operate off of some values in the join table within an ActiveModel::Serializer which we will be passing the collection through.

Comment: I like to call association class `Enrolment` instead of `CourseStudentJoin`. Personal preference

Comment: @DanielMyasnikov, I would as well, but let's not get into the nomenclature of this question.  I've come up with an example to outline an issue I'm encountering in a very large project, in hopes of avoiding the need to expose a larger than necessary context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most Rails-friendly method would be an auto-incrementing `id` integer primary key + a unique index on `(course_id, student_id)`.

Is there any reason you would want to be loading and the `CourseStudentJoin` records? It seems that you wouldn't want to manipulate them directly, anyways, and would be better off doing things like

```
Course.includes(:students).where(active: true, category: "Math").foo.bar
Student.includes(:courses).where(state: "CA").foo.bar
```

Comment: Just tried that, adding an ID field to the join table that won't ever be used, setting that ID field to be the primary_key (auto-inc) and it actually works.  It REALLY isn't pretty though... are there any directives/parameters/etc that could be specified on the has_many/belongs_to declarations or some tweaking of the actual AREL for the query?

In regards to loading the join records, yes we need to load them.  We are attaching extra (denormalized) data to the join record which needs to be referenced when the whole result set is passed along to an activemodel::serializer.

Comment: Also, is there non rails-friendly way that would not require the creation of an unused field/index on what will be a very large join table?

Comment: My best experience has been with pure join table `(x_id, y_id)`, tiny model file, or a full table `(id, x_id, y_id, data, ...)`. I don't think Rails handles composite primary keys well at all. Try `CourseStudentJoin.first`, `CourseStudentJoin#destroy`, `CourseStudentJoin#update_attributes` without a singular primary key. None worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you don't need a primary key for a join table. You can just specify `id: false` on the migration file.

Also be mindful of changing database parameters () without telling rails schema about these changes, you can update the schema by dry running `rake db:migrate`

The last thing you are looking for is HABTM relationship. has_and_belongs_to_many: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

All you need to is:

```
student = Student.find(1)
student.courses
```

Comment: The question is around an issue with eager loading and join tables.  I stated I need access to the join tables through an eager load.  This is not a simple HATBTM situation.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up.  Having a single, auto-incremeneting column as a primary key which would never be used, didn't sit well.  The composite_primary_keys gem does affect the eager_load mechanism within ActiveRecord and resolves the issue.  We hadn't considered it as we don't require the primary functionality of the gem, but it does solve this issue in the most acceptable manner.